# Oracle round robin sequence based on specific set of records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence, procedure

so i have these table

```
User table
NO| ID    | PID
1 | 00033 | P4
2 | 00033 | P3
3 | 00033 | P3
```

and

```
Program table 
NO | PROGRAM
1  | Prog-1
2  | Prog-2
3  | Prog-3
4  | Prog-4
5  | Prog-5
```

im expecting this result

```
NO| ID    | PID | PROGRAM_NO
1 | 00033 | P4  | 1
2 | 00033 | P3  | 2
3 | 00033 | P3  | 3
```

for the next batch the program_no should be countinued based on row count of program table

```
NO| ID    | PID | PROGRAM_NO
1 | 00033 | P4  | 4
2 | 00033 | P3  | 5
3 | 00033 | P3  | 1
```

the logic is to Assign  randomly-ordered program_no on program's table to user's tables in round-robin format . and needs to be continued on the next batch for the left over number.

i'd like to know how to achieve this on oracle.

Regards,
Rian

Comment: ok i edit the sample

Comment: so what is a logic behind ? can you use a sequence with  max value 5 and a cycle option?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I hope it can be useful for you:

```
select no, program from(
select 1, p1.* from program p1 where no > 3  --3 is the last assigned program
union all
select 2, p2.* from program p2
order by 1, 2
fetch first 3 rows only
);
```

Result:

[image]

Please note that for this solution you should always save the last program id that was assigned. For example you can do it in a separate table, or even adding a new column to Program table.